# Get value from header JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, http-headers

I need to extract the address from a returned header - the data being returned is as follows

```
{
    "error": false,
    "error_msg": "",
    "body": {
        "records": [
            {
                "address": "/Clients/I/imi_bit_contact_dev/web/app_dev.php/api/v/1/address/46813"
            }
        ]
    },
    "validation_errors": []
}
```

Currently there is only one address being returned and I need to grab this address (full url) for further usage.

Comment: why not `obj.body.records[0].address`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simply

`data.body.records[0].address`

where `data` is your returned response

Or

```
for (var i = 0; i < data.body.records.length; i++)
{
 var address = data.body.records[i].address;
 alert (address);
}
```

to get the multiples rows.

Comment: Excellent - the multiple row was probably my next question. I just got my [0] in the wrong place. Thanks